# manipulate data object sequelize ORM (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

i have code like :

```
data = await photo.findOne({
    where : {id}
})
```

that return data

```
{
     "a" : 2,
     "b" : 5
}
```

i want to manipulate the data like insert some field

so i add properties :

```
data.c = data.a * data.b
```

i check in console.log the data added

```
{
     "a" : 2,
     "b" : 5,
     "c" " 10
}
```

but when i return to json

```
 return res.status(200).json({message: "success", data })
```

the data still like first
    {
         "a" : 2,
         "b" : 5
    }

Comment: When you use sequelize, you write to a table. So the first thing is to check the table structure. Do you have a column 'c'? Also how is the ORM schema and how do save the data?

Comment: no i dont have column 'c', but i wanna add some properties "c" to object "data"

Comment: I understand now what you are trying to do. I guess your problem is a timing issue. Something with asynchronous code that is not executed in the order you think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for your problem is

> Finder methods are intended to query data from the database. They do not return plain objects but instead return model instances. Because finder methods return model instances you can call any model instance member on the result as described in the documentation for instances.

When you `data.c = data.a * data.b` do this, you are basically ***adding a property to the model instance not to the data object***.

You can do something like

```
dataInstance = await photo.findOne({
    where : {id}
})
data = dataInstance.get({
   plain: true // Important
})
data.c = data.a * data.b;
```

Cheers. Don't forget to make the answer verified.

Comment: wow i see, i'm misunterstanding for the model, but when i try , why return "dataInstance.get is not a function"

Comment: the answer is correct, thanks
the reason i got error "dataInstance.get is not a function", because the data still in array and i use .findAll()

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found answer after searching a lot. you should do something like this

```
const users = await db.users.findAll({})
.map(el => el.get({ plain: true })) // add this line to code
```

source :[Github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6950#issuecomment-373937803)